# Wix per user files,Can you not use the registry?

Tags: wix

So I have files that are saved per user under the "PersonalFolder" Wix folder.

It seems that to have these per user files, I have to use a RegistryKey as the KeyPath.

Several of these files are per user configuration files that we do not want to overwrite during install, so I'm using the Permenent flag. Well now my users want to do a "clean install" so they delete the configuration files, but the registry keys persist. So now when they reinstall the files are missing.

Is there anything I can do in the installer for this?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand...  can you rephrase it or give a code sample?

Comment: Registry entries installed by your package should be removed during an uninstall. Why aren't your users uninstalling the package instead of manually deleting the files?

Comment: Because they are users, they do screwy things.

Comment: We have some files flagged as permenent since they are persistent user data. The users want to have a "clean" install so they delete the files, but it leaves the reg key, so now they have an incomplete install.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are worried about the user deleting some of the files but not the registry keys before trying to install again. To account for this, your installer at the very beginning should check if anything is left over from the previous installation.

1. Check if the registry keys or directories exist
2. If they do, run a batch file to delete them before starting the actual installation.
3. Do the clean installation.

You can use CustomAction to run a batch file if some things are left over from the previous installation. Schedule the CustomAction in InstallExecuteSequence before the InstallFinalize.

Comment: That's not exactly the issue.

These aren't files I want to rewrite, they are settings files that have been personalized.